# Opencart .htaccess - allows access to specified folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, opencart

I've got an OpenCart site, but need to create an addtional /test directory which is accessible.

By default, all requests are sent to OpenCart. I'm trying to make it send all except /test. I've tried a few suggestions on this site already, but either nothing happens, or I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

This is the rewrite part of the OpenCart provided .htacccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I think I need a line like the following after `RewriteBase`, but can't get anything working yet.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to do anything. The lines `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` are conditions that say if the request is not a file and not a directory, the proceed. Otherwise it will not rewrite.

Comment: Ah, sorted it. I had directory indexes turned off, so was getting an OpenCart 404 page. Thanks for mentioning that or I would have missed it!

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test/(.*)
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

RewriteBase /YOUR_SUB_DIR/ 
replace 'YOUR_SUB_DIR' with yours